# Android4.0.4 contacts Install Failed

Tags: android, contacts

My phone is rooted. After modify contacts, pack and signature. It hint installation failure, and there is no share user or signature does not match this app on the phone.

I modify, pack and signature other app. It can install.

Why contacts have the error?

Comment: what does the log say? Is there any reason written why installation fails?

Comment: It hints: there is no share user or signature does not match this app on the phone.